# How to export a model in blender along with the node setup?

Tags: node-editor, export

I have created a mountains scene and added a lot of detail to it through displacements in node setups. Unfortunately when I try to export this whole scene, I only export the main model and not the node setups that modify the model when rendering it. Is there any way around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Export to what? if you mean into another Blender scene you can just append it from the file.

Comment: I want to export it to a .obj file to use in Unity.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/for-which-formats-are-cycles-materials-completely-and-accurately-exportedhttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24422/export-cycles-material-to-unity

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Unfortunately that question doesn't solve my problem. If you can, please point me to another similar question if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to bake your displacement into an image and use it in a displacement modifier to create an actual mesh that will be exportable to something like Unity.

Unfortunately the displacement generated from nodes won't become baked geometry, you can follow this video tutorial for the workaround.

https://youtu.be/McALCOr39rY